# Pandas: Resample from weekly to daily with offset

Tags: python, pandas

I want to resample this following dataframe from weekly to daily then `ffill` the missing values.

*Note: 2018-01-07 and 2018-01-14 is Sunday.*

```
         Date  Val
0  2018-01-07    1
1  2018-01-14    2
```

I tried.

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
offset = pd.offsets.DateOffset(-6)

df.resample('D', loffset=offset).ffill()

            Val
Date           
2018-01-01    1
2018-01-02    1
2018-01-03    1
2018-01-04    1
2018-01-05    1
2018-01-06    1
2018-01-07    1
2018-01-08    2
```

But I want

```
         Date  Val
0  2018-01-01    1
1  2018-01-02    1
2  2018-01-03    1
3  2018-01-04    1
4  2018-01-05    1
5  2018-01-06    1
6  2018-01-07    1
7  2018-01-08    2
8  2018-01-09    2
9  2018-01-10    2
10 2018-01-11    2
11 2018-01-12    2
12 2018-01-13    2
13 2018-01-14    2
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add new last row manually with subtract `offset` for `datetime`:

```
df.loc[df.index[-1] - offset] = df.iloc[-1]
df = df.resample('D', loffset=offset).ffill()
print (df)
            Val
Date           
2018-01-01    1
2018-01-02    1
2018-01-03    1
2018-01-04    1
2018-01-05    1
2018-01-06    1
2018-01-07    1
2018-01-08    2
2018-01-09    2
2018-01-10    2
2018-01-11    2
2018-01-12    2
2018-01-13    2
2018-01-14    2
```

Comment: Thanks! So if I want to resample backward, then I always have to this right?

Comment: @ResidentSleeper - I think yes.